# Convert 2D list, having 3 different values, into Dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, loops, dictionary

I was trying convert a 2d list in which a particular row includes 3 values, into dictionary.

Input i am having:

```
L1 = [ #Name  #runs  #balls
      ["Virat", 100, 60],
      ["Dhoni", 35, 30],
      ["Virat", 42, 55],
      ["Sachin", 0, 30],
      ["Jadeja", 60, 60],
     ]
```

Now the output I want:

```
d1 = {
      "Virat": { "runs": [100,42], "balls":[60,55] }
      "Dhoni": { "runs": [35], "balls":[30]}
      "Sachin": { "runs": [0], "balls":[30] }
      "Jadeja": { "runs": [60], "balls":[60] }
      }
```

The things is I want to this to be done with minimum nested loops (atmost 1).

Please help me on this!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
L1 = [  # Name  #runs  #balls
    ["Virat", 100, 60],
    ["Dhoni", 35, 30],
    ["Virat", 42, 55],
    ["Sachin", 0, 30],
    ["Jadeja", 60, 60],
]

out = {}
for n, r, b in L1:
    out.setdefault(n, {"runs": [], "balls": []})
    out[n]["runs"].append(r)
    out[n]["balls"].append(b)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{
    "Virat": {"runs": [100, 42], "balls": [60, 55]},
    "Dhoni": {"runs": [35], "balls": [30]},
    "Sachin": {"runs": [0], "balls": [30]},
    "Jadeja": {"runs": [60], "balls": [60]},
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works in one for loop run. Here i don't know much about dict.setdefault()... and may that's the reason i was using another for loop everytime. Once again Thanks.